# Regex to determine legal SQL?

Tags: sql, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression to match common SQL syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139926/regular-expression-to-match-common-sql-syntax)

I am writing some helpers to help generate some very domain-specific sql. In my test-suite it would be nice to add a sanity check to ensure that the results are actually valid SQL. I'm not doing anything particularly fancy and this isn't production code so I think some regex would do but it's still annoyingly difficult to write by hand.

Is anyone willing to share a regex expression that would validate valid SQL at least for the 90% case?

Comment: Cthulhu encourages using regex for SQL.

Comment: Where's Welbog when you need him?

Comment: I know we are closed here, but it should be doable to create a wrapper proc  that runs your SQL Code, traps errors, and always rolls back.

Comment: @JNK: nice idea. The proc could also try not to run the actual query but try an `EXPLAIN` on it (or equivalent).

Comment: @JNK - Not a bad idea at all, I think I already even have a sqlite instance spun up. If I get anything back but a "table does not exist" error I know the sql is malformed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). Use a real validator, such as [Mimer](http://sqlvalidator.mimer.com/index.html).

#### See also:

- [Is SQL or even TSQL Turing Complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900055/is-sql-or-even-tsql-turing-complete)
- [Regular expression to match common SQL syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139926/regular-expression-to-match-common-sql-syntax)

Comment: +1.  Nice!  I didn't know that existed.

Comment: @David: neither did I, until I Googled [`sql validator`](http://www.google.com/search?q=sql+validator).

Comment: These links are certainly interesting, but I don't need to match all of sql, just whatever standard cases we can get. Certainly going out to a web-service is not appropriate for unit tests.

Comment: @George: personally, that's not how I'd write my unit tests. Unit tests should test **actual units of code.** If using a web service isn't right for you, why wouldn't you just test your SQL against your actual database?