# Find an replace Guid to binary equivalent with regular expression

Tags: c#, sql, regex, sqlite, guid

I have a string containing a regular SQL-Statement with Guids. The statement should be converted so I can run it against a local SQLite database which cannot handle Guids as described by .NET-Framework.
Therefore I have to convert them to their binary representation, which means that the Guid (in SQL) '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' will become X'00000000000000000000000000000000' for SQLite or 'FE334797-0A46-468D-91F2-0005F1EC67EC' will become X'974733fe460a8d4691f20005f1ec67ec'.

The method to convert a single Guid is as follows:

```
private static string GetBinaryGuid(Guid guidToConvert)
{
    var guidBytes = guidToConvert.ToByteArray();
    var guidBinary = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var guidByte in guidBytes)
    {
        guidBinary.AppendFormat(@"{0}", guidByte.ToString("x2"));
    }
    return guidBinary.ToString();
}
```

The method to find the real Guid(s) in the query-string is:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\b[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-F0-9]{12}\b", "'$0'", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

My question is how to replace the "real" Guid(s) in the string with their respective binary equivalent?

**Edit:** Just to clarify. I want to fetch all Guid in the string, pass the found Guids to the method mentioned above and replace it within the string.
The result should be the SQL-Query with the binary Guid(s) if found in the string.

**Edit2:**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id = 'FE334797-0A46-468D-91F2-0005F1EC67EC'
```

should become

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id = X'974733fe460a8d4691f20005f1ec67ec'
```

**Edit3:**

@aelor got me the right direction.
For my specific case the solution can be found [here](http://regex101.com/r/jR8qN7).

Comment: Is the SQL string completely arbitrary, or will it always be in some known form?

Comment: No. The query-string could contain any number of Guid(s). Even none

Comment: Why not simply store the GUIDs as strings?  Aside from saving a tiny amount of storage, what benefit is there in converting to binary form for storage (presumably only then to convert back to string form again on data retrieval)?  If you absolutely *must* convert the data, why not do so in SQLite itself (e.g. using triggers for writes and views for reads)?

Comment: @eggyal: The query will first be executed on SQL-Server. If the query is what you expect you will add it to the system which will push it to the clients application which will execute the query there (against SQLite). So this is just for simplicity. Add the statement in SQL and convert it in the back so it can be executed on client side. Triggers would put too much effort on this. It's just a nice-to-have feature

Comment: Why doesn't the app that generates the code for the SQL server generate an appropriate query for SQLite if needed, instead of attempting to do this via string transformation?  Or pass off sufficient state to the client for it to so generate the statement?  Performing this operation through string manipulation, without parsing the SQL, is just poor programming IMHO.

Comment: And in any event, I don't think you've explained why the SQLite database cannot store the field as a text string per my suggestion above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know this is very big but thats what I could come up with:

```
\b([A-F0-9]{2})([A-F0-9]{2})([A-F0-9]{2})([A-F0-9]{2})-([A-F0-9]{2})([A-F0-9]{2})-([A-F0-9]{2})([A-F0-9]{2})-([A-F0-9]{2})([A-F0-9]{2})-([A-F0-9]{12})\b
```

use this and you will get your result in matched groups.

The replacement string will look like this :

```
X'\4\3\2\1\6\5\8\7\9\10\11'
```

use a `\L` for making it lowercase.\

[**Demo here**](http://regex101.com/r/cW6iN0)

if you are having trouble like this :

```
'X'974733FE460A91F20005F1EC67EC''
```

you can easily remove the leading and trailing `'` by using a function

```
public class Main {   
  /**
   * Remove the leading and trailing quotes from <code>str</code>.
   * E.g. if str is '"one two"', then 'one two' is returned.
   *
   *
   * @return The string without the leading and trailing quotes.
   */
  static String stripLeadingAndTrailingQuotes(String str)
  {
      if (str.startsWith("\'"))
      {
          str = str.substring(1, str.length());
      }
      if (str.endsWith("\'"))
      {
          str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
      }
      return str;
  }

}
```

Comment: Awesome. This is nearly what I want to have. But I do also need the single Quotas to be replaced: 'Guid-Value' -> X'Binary-Value'. How could this be added?

Comment: can you please elaborate I dont get it, which quotes you are talking about

Comment: [SQL is not a regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5639859), so one cannot solve this problem with regex alone.

Comment: @eggyal you are right, but here look at it as a simple string which has to be replaced.

Comment: @aelor I mean the single quotation mark ' should also be in the replacement. Because if I replace '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' it will become 'X'00000000000000000000000000000000'' instead of X'00000000000000000000000000000000' only.

Comment: @KingKerosin oo thats simple , just add a single quote in the replacement string, X'\4\3\2\1\6\5\9\10\11' hope that helps. I will edit it.

Comment: @aelor: Sorry, but eventually I am too dumb. But still SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id = 'FE334797-0A46-468D-91F2-0005F1EC67EC' will become SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id = 'X'974733FE460A91F20005F1EC67EC''. See the single quoatation marks around X'...'?

Comment: actually the resulting string is X'974733FE460A91F20005F1EC67EC' , okay now for showing it as a string one single quote is added on both the sides, thats the thing

Comment: Or you can do one thing , give me one example of sql query that works in your system, i will modify the text accordingly, does SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id = 'X'974733FE460A91F20005F1EC67EC'' or SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id = 'X\'974733FE460A91F20005F1EC67EC\'' work ?

Comment: It should only result in SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id = X'974733FE460A91F20005F1EC67EC' with the single quot marks around the binary value but no single quote before the X and after the binary. Hope you know what I mean.

Comment: check my update, thats all I could come up with , phew

Comment: @aelor The replacement string was missing part 7 and 8. It should be X'/4/3/2/1/6/5/8/7/9/10/11'. But at least, this was the solution I was looking for. Thanks very much

Comment: @KingKerosin OOHH i didnt notice it, thanks, i have updated the answer

Comment: My point is, performing such a pattern match on an SQL string could match non-GUID expressions (for example, an arithmetic expression involving five columns that happen to be so named).  Sure, it's unlikely to ever occur - but relying on that is IMHO poor programming.