# Taking the content of a line without the tags from an XML file

Tags: xml, f#

My program has an xml file as input, and I want to take only the content of a certain line, without the xml tags..
For example:

```
<string> xxx </string>
```

How can i get only the "xxx"?

Comment: Don't use a regex, go with XPath instead.

Comment: Why always regex? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex

Comment: ok, i won't use regex :)
I was just checking the options..

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments, you should not use regular expressions to parse XML, because .NET has better libraries for doing that. Here is an example using the `XDocument` type from LINQ to XML:

```
// Reference assemblies for LINQ to XML
#r "System.Xml.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"

open System.Xml.Linq

// Create document with your XML data
let doc = XDocument.Parse("<string> xxx </string>")
let el name = XName.Get(name)
// Get element named 'string' and pick its value
doc.Element(el "string").Value
```

Comment: Thanks. And if I want it to take the value, no matter what's the tag name? Is there an option?

Comment: @cookya If it is a root element, then you can write `doc.Root.Value`. Otherwise you need to take the first element returned by `Elements()` and write something like `(doc.Elements() |> Seq.head).Value`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"

open System
open System.Linq
open System.Xml.Linq

let toXName s = XName.Get s

let xml = XDocument.Load @"data.xml"
let getElements elName = xml.Root.Descendants(toXName elName)

let main() = 
  (getElements "string").First().Value
  |> printfn "%s"
//  getElements "string" |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%s" x.Value)

do main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using nested tags, you could use the folowing (just need to get the first group):

```
<.*?>([^<]*)<.*?>
```

but if you really use nested tags in your xml, you cannot get the values only by regex, it needs a stack or some sort of List to do so.

Comment: Seriously? An XML document with no nested tags?

Comment: Anything is possible, since we don't know his xml file's structure and what he's trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm not gonna downvote the answer cause it's technically correct. But still, its usefulness is close to none and IMO, it doesn't point anywhere close to the right direction.