# how to find out a string match with regex

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have this java string. Note there are two `<c></c>` pairs one contains only numbers but the other one contains numbers and a string.
How do I know if a string contains `<c></c>` with only numbers in Java?
I did this but it didn't work.

```
    String keyPattern = "^<id>[0-9]</id>$";
    boolean hasKey = str.matches(keyPattern);

<start><a></a><b></b><c>addf123</c><d><d><c>1234</c><foo></foo><bar></bar></start>
```

Comment: In a general sense, you should really be parsing the data properly with an XML parser. Parsing using regex is not the right thing to do.

Comment: Please do not use regex to parse XML.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of errors.

1. You have no tags "< id>" or "< /id>" inside of your string, you
   have "< /c>".
2. The special character "^" means it must match from the start of the string.  "$" means it must match till then end of the string. So in this case you want to match everything, up until the "< c>digits< /c>", then match the rest. ".* " will match everything up until what you want, then you should search for the digits, then match the rest of the string using ".*"
3. You are only searching with one digit with the "[0-9]" you need to search for 1 or more, this is done with the "+" symbol

revised matches that works.

```
String keyPattern = ".*<c>[0-9]+</c>.*";
boolean hasKey = str.matches(keyPattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close, you need to add a 'quantifier'. In your case, a '+'.

```
String keyPattern = "^<id>[0-9]+</id>$";
```

Link to the [JavaDoc for Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Edit: BUT, you also only going to successfully match a string where the *only* values in the String are `"<id>123</id>"` and no other text, because you have the ^ and $ anchors.

So, if you remove those, you have:

```
String keyPattern = ".*<id>[0-9]+</id>.*";
```

Which will match any string which contains a number-only ... tag *anywhere*.

I suspect that you want to get *all* the number-only id's, in which case, the matches(...) method is not the one you want to use.... but that's a different issue.

Comment: This keyPattern will not match the string when using str.matches

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a string that can contain a number of any size you need to add a + after the [0-9] so it looks like this:

```
[0-9]+
```

The way it is now it will only match a single digit number.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions to parse XML.  Use a real XML API, such as SAX or DOM--or, if applicable, some higher-level API which is less tedious to use.  For example, if you're using XML to serialize objects, you should look at [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/).

Trying to do it with regular expressions is just asking for trouble.  See related questions and their answers:

[Why is it such a bad idea to parse XML with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex)

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score -1):

`[0-9]` will match a single digit

`[0-9]?` will match 0 or 1 digits

`[0-9]*` will match 0 or many digits

`[0-9]+` will match 1 or many digits

you can also replace `[0-9]` with `\d` for a digit