# Regular expression for repeated sequence

Tags: regex

i am a learner of regular expressions. I am trying to find the date from the below string. **The element `<ext:serviceitem>` can be repeated upto 20 times in actual xml.** I need to take out only the date strings (like any element ending with Date in its name, i need that element's value which is a date). For example  and . I want all those dates (only) to be printed out.

```
<ext:serviceitem><ext:name>EnhancedSupport</ext:name><ext:serviceItemData><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="Name">E69D7F93-81F4-09E2-E043-9D3226AD8E1D-1</ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="ProductionDatabase">P1APRD</ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="SupportType">Monthly</ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="Environment">DV1</ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="StartDate">2013-11-04 10:02</ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="EndDate">2013-11-12 10:02</ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="No_of_WeeksSupported"></ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="Cost"></ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="SupportNotes"></ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="FiscalQuarterNumber"></ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:subscription><ext:loginID>kbasavar</ext:loginID><ext:ouname>020072748</ext:ouname></ext:subscription></ext:serviceItemData></ext:serviceitem><ext:serviceitem><ext:name>EnhancedSupport</ext:name><ext:serviceItemData><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="Name">E69D7F93-81F4-09E2-E043-9D3226AD8E1D-2</ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="ProductionDatabase">P1BPRD</ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="SupportType">Quarterly</ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="Environment">TS2</ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="StartDate">2013-11-11 10:03</ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="EndDate">2013-11-28 10:03</ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="No_of_WeeksSupported"></ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="Cost"></ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="SupportNotes"></ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:serviceItemAttribute name="FiscalQuarterNumber"></ext:serviceItemAttribute><ext:subscription><ext:loginID>kbasavar</ext:loginID><ext:ouname>020072748</ext:ouname></ext:subscription></ext:serviceItemData></ext:serviceitem>
```

I tried with below regex, but its returning rest of the string after the first occurence.

```
(?<=Date\"\>).*(?=\<\/ext\:serviceItemAttribute\>)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex), please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `.*`  is greedy, meaning that it will grab from the first instance of `Date` to the last instance of `</ext:ser....`. Replace the `.*` with `.*?` and it will alter the behaviour to what you're after.

```
#(?<=Date">).*?(?=</ext:serviceItemAttribute>)#i
```

You should have `.*?` in a capture group: `(.*?)`.

```
#(?<=Date">)(.*?)(?=</ext:serviceItemAttribute>)#i
```

You could also do it - *more simply* - like:

```
#Date">(.*?)</ext#i
```

#### Update

As has been pointed out in the comment below this (above) solution relies on the use of non-greedy matching.

To get around this you could use the following: `([^<]*)` instead of `(.*?)`

**NOTE:** This does not impact the alternatives below.

---

### Alternatives

```
/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/
/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2})/
```

The above patterns will match dates in the format `YYYY-XX-XX` and `YYYY-XX-XX HH:MM` respectively

Comment: This, of course, assumes that your regular expression dialect supports non-greedy matching.  The OP had better include information about the platform so we don't have to guess about which regex features are supported by the available tool(s).

Comment: Thank you very much. This one `(?<=Date">)(.*?)(?=</ext:serviceItemAttribute>)` worked for me.

Comment: Good to know it worked! @tripleee: A valid point, it turns out that it did work in this case. However, I have updated the answer with a workaround.