# How can i convert xml file to html file without xslt

Tags: html, xml

My Question is that How can i convert a xml file in to html using java code without using xslt functionality,and should be displayed as similar.

Please help us,i am very frustrated.

Comment: DOM, SAX, [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex), there are many choices.

Comment: if we use regex or Sax then we have to do lot of modification in xml,but i need very less change in xml.

Comment: It's a bit like asking how to cut your hedge without a hedge-trimmer. It can be done (use nail scissors), but the attempt will cause frustration.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite Java, but I have found Groovy's `XMLSlurper` and `MarkupBuilder` to be quite powerful for this purpose. The syntax is close enough to Java where there is no real learning curve.

See [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/parsing-xml-groovy-using) and [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+XML+using+Groovy%27s+MarkupBuilder).