# How to match values in double quotes?

Tags: java, xml, regex

I'd like to mask out sensitive credit card details. Therefore trying to create matcher that finds:

- that there is a CreditCard tag
- that the same line has a Number field
- that the same line has a CVC field

> <CreditCard Number="123456789" CVC="111" />

Then I want to replace the numbers/values that are found.
So far I have: `(CreditCard.*CVC=").*?"`. This would match the string `CreditCard Number="123456789" CVC="111"`.

What do I have to change so that only the numbers inside either CVC or Number double quotes are matched?

Comment: Try XPath instead of Regex.

Comment: What language are you using?  It would probably be a much better idea to use an XML parser

Comment: Java, but the string where the XML is placed does not ONLY consist of xml, but lot's of other data. So I cannot use a parser...

Comment: Are those attributes always in this order? Or could CVC occur before Number?

Comment: [Don't parse XML with regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex)

Comment: Probably it will have the same order, but I'm not sure about the future...

Comment: Why are you parsing XML with regex?  You lose the benefits of using a markup language that has many excellent libraries for manipulating values like you want.

Comment: I know I lose, but as I wrote above the content that I want to match is not only xml, but also lot's of noise content. Then I first would have to strip out everything that does not belong right to the xml request, which feels like doing unnecessary double work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookahead and Lookbehind are the magic words. Here is an example to match your CVC number...

```
(?<=CVC=\")\d+(?=\")
```

Comment: However, this doesn't ensure that we're inside a `CreditCard` tag while matching `CVC`.

Comment: Yes, it is an example but easy to extend. I thought his main problem was to understand how to ignore the double quotes.

Comment: Not easy to extend, though. Java doesn't support `*` or `+` inside a lookbehind.