# Java replace regex before and after a period

Tags: java, regex

I am working with XML on an android app that sometimes leaves sentences bumped up against each other.

Like: `First sentence.Another sentence`

I know I need to use `[a-z]` (lowercase letters), `[A-Z]` (uppercase letters), and all digits (`[0-9]?`) to search before and after the period, and then add a space after the period.

Maybe something like:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("(\\p{Ll})(\\p{Lu})", "$1 $2");
```

My searches and efforts have been useless so far, so any and all help is welcomed. Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you come up with a better title than `I can not find this regex`?

Comment: Your title sounds like you've [lost your regex, and you need help finding it](https://xkcd.com/1313/).

Comment: Never parse XML with regex.XML is not a regular language.Use well known XML parsers instead.See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex

Comment: at the time of me making edits to XML, it is already a well formatted string

Comment: At what point are these sentences stuck together without a space? Does the XML itself have sentences joined improperly, with no spaces or tags between them?

Comment: I have no idea where the problem occurs at. I am editing a string obtained through a RSS XML feed that mainly provides info on the web, but for some reason when I collect it to android, it comes up missing spaces like these.

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there, you just forgot to match the dot:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("(\\p{Ll})\\.(\\p{Lu})", "$1. $2");
```

And since you're not actually doing anything with the letter before and after the dot, you can speed things up a bit by using [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("(?<=\\p{Ll})\\.(?=\\p{Lu})", ". ");
```

Comment: Of course, now we're putting extra spaces into acronyms written with periods. We could try to tell whether we're looking at an acronym, but then we run into *more* edge cases. Natural language correction is messy.

Comment: yes, but this is still missing the fact that it could be a number, lowercase letter, or uppercase letter before and after the period.

Comment: I know this is a messy thing to edit... but there will be very very few of these cases I think

Comment: If you also want to replace dots after uppercase letters and digits, just use `[\\p{L}\\d]` instead of `\\p{Ll}`, but then you'd also replace `C.I.A.` with `C. I. A.`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Didn't see that the lookarounds were specifically lowercase and uppercase. It means we're missing *different* weird edge cases, but C.I.A. is currently fine.

Comment: hi can i optimize this , am calling this like #1 in my web applilcationo for generating sql statments ?