# Escape unescaped data of XML string in python3

Tags: python, xml, regex, escaping, beautifulsoup

I want to escape the unescaped data inside a xml string
e.g.

```
string = "<tag parameter = "something">I want to escape these >, < and &</tag>"
```

to

```
"<tag parameter = "something">I want to escape these &gt;, &lt; and &amp;</tag>"
```

- Now, I definitely can't use any xml parsing libraries like xml.dom.minidom or xml.etree because the data is unescaped & will give error
- In regex, I figure out way to match & get start and end positions of data substing

  ```
  exp = re.search(">.+?</", label)
  # Get position of the data between tags
  start = exp.start() + 1
  end = exp.end() - 2
  return label[ : start] + saxutils.escape(label[start : end]) + label[end : ]
  ```
- But in **re.search**, I can't match the exact xml format
- If I use **re.findall** I  can't get positions of the substrings found
- I could always find positions of found substring by **index** but that won't be efficient, I want a simple but efficent solution
- BeautifulSoup solutions are welcomed but I wish there was some more beautiful way to do it with python's basic libraries

Comment: And how was this faulty XML produced in the first place? It'd be easier if you could fix that instead..

Comment: in string you have `,` instead of `.` in `">.+?</"`, maybe thats why you can't match anything in re.search

Comment: @Aleksandar the above program snippet works absolutely fine

Comment: Sure @MartijnPieters, but I'm in a time crunch and this is the **hack** I could come up with :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you should be considering `re.sub`:

```
>>> oldString = '<tag parameter = "something">I want to escape these >, < and &</tag>'
>>> newString = re.sub(r"(<tag.*?>)(.*?)</tag>", lambda m: m.group(1) + cgi.escape(m.group(2)) + "</tag>", oldString)
>>> print newString
<tag parameter = "something">I want to escape these &gt;, &lt; and &amp;</tag>
```

My warning is that **the regular expression will definitely break if you have nested tags**. See [Why is it such a bad idea to parse XML with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex)

Comment: its really efficient form of my code, but my primary concern is to match the enclosing tags <tag.*> and </tag> also using regex

Comment: @prth I edited the code to match <tag> tags. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you wanted.