# Extracting text with script

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

We have an xml file of the following format:

```
<mailBox>
...
</mailBox>
<mailBox>demon</mailBox>
<tz>16385</tz>
<Contact>
....
</Contact>
</mailBox>
<mailBox>
...
</mailBox>
```

Is there a way to extract a particular node out of this xml using a sed/awk/grep one-liner?
I was looking for somethign in the format

```
`sed -n 'mailBox\>demon,......p`
```

Comment: Don't attempt to parse XML using regex.  `xmlstarlet` might help.

Comment: Yes, trying to parse XML with regexp is a *bad* idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex ...

Comment: thanks - but its a pretty simple xml for me(without nested tags).And i needed a quick hit for troubleshooting.

Comment: Or, similar answer for HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491

Answer (score 0):

on your sample the tag demon is on the same line and not in rest of file. Error or specific

If it's an error (so mailbox tag are on separate lines)

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;${x
s/.*\(<mailBox>demon.*\)/\1/;s|</mailBox>.*||;p
}' YourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
perl -0777 -nE 'foreach (/<mailBox>(.*?)<\/mailBox>/sg) {say $_}' file
```