# How to get node value from xml?

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to read a xml file from /data/data/aas/a.xml. But I don't know how to get started. I well remounted /data as rw and chmod 777 /data/data/a.xml. It is rooted.
It works on adb well .

My xml format is ...

```
<map>
    <string name="aaa">123</string>
    <string name="bbb">222</string>
    ...
    ...
    <string name="ccc">999</string>
</map>
```

I want to get the value of ccc(999) in that way. How can I achieve it .Please help me please .. I am very new to android programming ! Please give me full explanation .

Code In my onCreate()..

```
  process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
  os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
  os.writeBytes("mount -o remount rw /data");
  os.writeBytes("chmod 777 data/data/com.aas.a/a.xml");
```

...
In a.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
  <map>
     <string name="ccc">0000</string>
  </map>
```

... 
I want 0000 from this . Thank you ..

Comment: you just want to get cc?

Comment: 999 (value of ccc) .. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use DOM with java. Here's an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/).

Comment: It is too complicated. Can show write some samples with mine. If possible. Thank you so much for Answering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dom4j with java and use the XPATH command to get the value you want, if you don't mind to add [the library](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) to your project:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws DocumentException{
    org.dom4j.Document doc = null;
    File theXml = new File("pathToXml.xml");

    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    doc = (org.dom4j.Document) reader.read(theXml);
    Element elem = (Element) doc.selectSingleNode("/map/string[@name='ccc']");
    System.out.println(elem.getStringValue());
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me the direct download link jar file to add to my library folder!

Comment: Get [dom4j](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1) along with [jaxen](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jaxen/jaxen/1.1.6) and you should be good to go.

Comment: I think you will be annoyed with me .. I am very very new to android programming .. I don't know how to call it on my onCreate() :D .. 
And this line is under auto correct like that . . I am still dull .. 
System.out.println(((Node) elem).getStringValue());

Comment: You should probably create an another question for that.

Comment: No problem, I'm Happy to help! That said, if this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

if you want just the `ccc` of your xml then you can just use a pattern that will split the string between the tag.

**try this:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("name=\"ccc\">(.*?)</string>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(your_xml_here);
if (m.find()) 
  Log.d("result: ",m.group(1)); // => "3"
```

where `your_xml_here` is the xml in string form
......

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex .. Generally I advice against parsing xml using regex. It's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: if your pattern meet my xml pattern ? It still doesn't work .

Comment: @user3517970 when you print your xml string what does it look like?

Comment: sorry .I just edited in your answer to be clear . No result log nor response to your code when it runs . Thank you.

Comment: @user3517970, please stop adding comments to peoples questions and answers. Add your own comment or add your own answer.

Comment: @user3517970 show my what have you dont in your code post it

Comment: sorry. I corrected it. Please advice me to get the result ! Thank you .

Comment: @user3517970 what code have you written yet in your activity?? post it.

Comment: Yes, I posted it . Thank you. I am new to android programming.