# Pattern matching software builds

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need to check if a XML document contains some software build numbers

normally they're like ######, where:

- First two characters are numbers
- Third character is a letter in uppercase
- last three characters are numbers

Example: 10B329 or 11A465.

But there could be some exceptions, like 8L1 or 11B465a. (if there's another character after the sixth, it's always a letter in lowercase).

I think they're always with a minimum length of 3 characters and a maximum length of 7 characters.

So what could be the best pattern to match? I tried this but it doesn't work since it takes also words...

```
Dim BuildPattern As String = "<key>[0-9A-Z]*</key>"
```

Comment: Just FYI : [you shouldn't parse XML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex)

Comment: Do you just need to get all the `key` tag inner texts? If yes, use an XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex: `\d{2}\w\d{3}`

You can see a live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/yF5uP8/1).

You can add the `<key></key>` tags too: `<key>(\d{2}\w\d{3})<\/key>`. This way, your match will be in group 1 of the match. [Changed demo.](https://regex101.com/r/yF5uP8/2)

Note that you should rather use **XML parser** for this as it's safer and more accurate than working with regex on XML files.

EDIT: Can't help you with the non-standard length though, my knowledge of regexes is still too low. Perhaps you really should try **XML parser** instead?

Comment: *But there could be some exceptions, like 8L1 or 11B465a.* and *I think they're always with a minimum lenght of 3 characters and a maximum lenght of 7 characters.*