# Parse a string for open and close tags

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11

Let's say I have the following strings:

- "This [color=RGB]is[\color] a string."
- "This [color=RGB][bold]is[\bold][\color] another string."

What I'm looking for is a good way to parse the string in order to extract the tag information and then reconstruct the original string without tags.
The tag informations will be used during text rendering.

Obviously I can achieve the goal by working directly with strings (find/substr/replace and so on), but I'm asking if there is another way cleaner, for example using regular expression.

**Note:**

- There are very few tags I need, but there is the possibility to nest them (only of different type).
- Can't use Boost.

Comment: "Can't use Boost." Then, how about using flex & bison? (Sorry, I'm not sure if it can be archived with these tools.)

Comment: this is similar to HTML - can you make your life easier, and switch to HTML (or another well-supported markup language). You can then use existing libraries for parsing/rendering/...

Comment: Don't use regex. Nested tags are no fun in regex. Also you might want to read the answers on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex

Comment: You might want to mention if the tag format is following something that is a standard, for example BBCode or similar. There are probably dedicated parsing libraries that would be much easier to use, faster, and less error-prone than parsing it with regex.

Comment: What about unmatched tags? e.g. `"This is[\color] a string."` or `"This [color=RGB]is a string."`?

Comment: @SimonKraemer yes, I can use unmatched tags, with the rule that the tag influence only the following word (or something like that).

Comment: @KennethBruno no, at the moment is not following a standard, but I need a very few tags (at the moment : color with color value, bold, animation with the animation type, a string). All of this is for a custom text rendering in a game.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple answer that might work, depending on the complexity of your strings. (And me understanding you correctly, i.e. you just want to get the *cleaned up* strings, not actually extract the tags.) Just remove all tags. Replace

```
\[.*?]
```

with nothing. [Example here](https://regex101.com/r/cI2hF0/1)

Now, if your string should be able to contain tag-like objects this might not work.

Regards

Comment: No, as first step I need to parse the tags and fill some structure (eg. from where to where the text is to be colored).
Then, yes, I need the cleaned up string.