# RegEx in JavaScript: Content Between Two Tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xml, find

I need to extract the content between two XML tags, excluding the tags.

*PS: I won't be using this just to parse XML. I'll be using the RegEx in JavaScript, so the lookbehind won't work.*

What am I doing wrong?

XML:

```
<location maps="">
    RewriteMap map txt:map.txt
    RewriteMap lower int:tolower
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/.]+)\.html$ [NC]
    RewriteCond ${map:${lower:%1}|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
    RewriteRule .? /index.php?q=${map:${lower:%1}} [NC,L]
</location>
```

RegEx:

```
/(?:(?=(\<(?!\/)(.*?)\>)))([\s\S]*?)(?=(\<(?=\/)(.*?)\>))/igm
```

---

Results:

```
<location maps="">
    RewriteMap map txt:map.txt
    RewriteMap lower int:tolower
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/.]+)\.html$ [NC]
    RewriteCond ${map:${lower:%1}|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
    RewriteRule .? /index.php?q=${map:${lower:%1}} [NC,L]
```

**What I Want**

```
RewriteMap map txt:map.txt
RewriteMap lower int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/.]+)\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond ${map:${lower:%1}|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
RewriteRule .? /index.php?q=${map:${lower:%1}} [NC,L]
```

Comment: There must be a super easy and robust way if you can use any decent XML parser, instead of doing this with regex; [Why is it such a bad idea to parse XML with regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex)

Comment: Actually it's just an example, I'll be using it for anything, HTML, XML, even if I have to get content between two 'Things' with multiple lines.

Comment: What environment? JS, php, editor...?

Comment: I'll be using it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following regex: (if tag name is constant)

```
<location[^>]*>([^<]+)</location>
```

Comment: That still has a result with the tags in.

Comment: I have made regex based on your given example. 
It is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<(\w+)[^>]+>\n*([\s\S]*)<\/\1>
```

It'll grab your tag, capture everything up to tag repeated prefixed with `/`.

Result in capture group 2.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xR6lB6/1).

Comment: That's not quite what I am looking for. I already have a fixed JavaScript RegEx Template and the only thing that changes is the RegEx.

Comment: Don't quite follow... Do you mean you have to use the match, not capture groups?

Comment: The template will loop through the RegEx that was put into it. The template will find the RegEx and replace it with something. I wouldn't want to change the template just for one RegEx option when I have 123 more RegEx options. I need the RegEx to just capture what is between the two tags, excluding the tags.

Comment: Then I don't see a way of doing it since JS don't have look behinds.