# Regex nested backreference

Tags: regex

Is it possible to get a nested back reference to the below regex:

```
<field(.*)name="(.*)EndTime"(.*)\n((.*)\n)*?<property name="fieldClass" value="java.lang.String"/>\n</field>
```

Ie the `"((.*)\n)*?"`

Comment: Don't parse XML with RegEx! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is quite possible. Just be certain to watch for which numbered group you're using. Capturing groups (and thus backreferences) are numbered according to which opening bracket comes first - so, in this case, the outer brackets would yield `\1`, and the inner ones would yield `\2`.

For example, the pattern `((.+)ab)\1\2` will match the string `1234ab1234ab1234`. The first capture group will match the 4 numbers plus the `ab`, while the second (inner) capture group will only match the numbers. Then we repeat each one, yielding the full match.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning named capturing groups to avoid getting mixed up on which group is which and being able to explicitly reference a certain group.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean here. Can you provide a example?

Comment: [you can name your capturing groups](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html#namedgroups) and back-reference them with those names. Although not directly answering the question put forward, I thought it was worth mentioning to avoid any confusion caused by the nested brackets. You can then do something like `(?<first>ab(?<second>ba))` to have `${first} == abba` and `${second} == ba`