# regex to mask all account numbers in XML up to the last four digits

Tags: java, regex, xml, replace

I'm trying to mask all the occurences of **AccountNumber** in my XML response code. The AccountNumber has 16 digits and I want to mask first 12 digits and retain last four.

XML response:

```
<ns2:PaymentMethod>
  <CCInfo xmlns="">
           <AccountType>sdaj</AccountType>
           <AccountNumber>1234567890123456</AccountNumber>
           <AccountName>sdfsad</AccountName>
           <ExpirationMonth>sdaf</ExpirationMonth>
           <ExpirationYear>afgds</ExpirationYear>
    </CCInfo>
  </ns2:PaymentMethod>
  <ns2:PaymentMethod>
  <CCInfo xmlns="">
           <AccountType>kyfkuk</AccountType>
           <AccountNumber>098765432123987</AccountNumber>
           <AccountName>hjvkv</AccountName>
           <ExpirationMonth>gfdgh</ExpirationMonth>
           <ExpirationYear>tdjk</ExpirationYear>
    </CCInfo>
  </ns2:PaymentMethod>
```

Below is my java code:

```
String accountNumberPatternString ="<AccountNumber>(^.{12})";
Pattern accountNumberPattern = Pattern.compile(accountNumberPatternString);
Matcher matcher = accountNumberPattern.matcher(data);
String maskedResult = matcher.replaceAll("<AccountNumber>*******");
```

I'm expecting the result as:

```
<AccountNumber>************3456</AccountNumber>
```

but I'm getting the result as:

```
<AccountNumber>1234567890123456</AccountNumber>
```

Comment: why is this `^` in your pattern?

Comment: one solution would be to extract the AN from the xml. once you have it : you can use : String.format("%1$" + AN.length() + "s", AN.subString(13,15).replace(" ","*");

Comment: hopefully you are using a valid method to convert the xml stream to a String so as to not corrupt the data in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that you are aware of the [dangers of parsing XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex), but let's ignore that for now.

Based on your updated requirements, that the length of the account number can vary, I would suggest the use of [Matcher.appendReplacement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-), like so:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=<AccountNumber>)\\d*(?=\\d{4})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
    StringBuffer maskedResult = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        String thisMask = m.group(0).replaceAll(".", "*");
        m.appendReplacement(maskedResult, thisMask);
    }
    m.appendTail(maskedResult);
    System.out.println(maskedResult.toString());
```

Note in the above example I have used positive lookbehind `(?<=)` to identify the start of Account Number, then positive lookahead `(?=)` to ensure that four digits remain.

Finally, here's a more robust version that handles account numbers with letters, spaces, and/or dashes, such as `"<AccountNumber> 123 456-78901FFA-56C </AccountNumber>"`:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=<AccountNumber>)([-\\s\\w]*)((?:[a-zA-Z0-9][-_\\s]*){4})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
    StringBuffer maskedResult = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        String thisMask = m.group(1).replaceAll("[^-_\\s]", "*");
        m.appendReplacement(maskedResult, thisMask + "$2");
    }
    m.appendTail(maskedResult);
    System.out.println(maskedResult.toString());
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error in the line m.appendReplacement(maskedResult, thisMask);   The method appendReplacement(StringBuffer, String) in the type Matcher is not applicable for the arguments (StringBuilder, String)

Comment: @eureka19 Oh right sorry. I guess you have to use StringBuffer not StringBuilder. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `^` is wrong. And if you only have numbers, you should also only match numbers with `\d`. And the `()` parantheses are unnecessary.

https://regex101.com/r/Uu6qTR/1

```
<AccountNumber>\d{12}
```

Comment: When I use String accountNumberPatternString ="<AccountNumber>\d{12}"; I'm getting the error: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: Well... of course... you need to double escape the backslash because it's inside a string.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka is right.
eureka19, try to use : <AccountNumber>\\d{12}

Comment: @FlorianPeschka It works fine thanks. What will be the change if the length of the account number varies. Is there a way to say that I want to mask the entire account number except for the last four digits? That will fix my problem of variable length account number.

Comment: @eureka19 For that case I would advise you to go the route that Tom mentioned in a comment to your question. It's easier and less confusing in the code.