# Finding text between two tags with variable namespace

Tags: regex

I have to parse a lot of text files where each text file contain one or more XML documents. I do know every XML is wrapped in a Envelope tag as root tag, but they have varying namespaces.
I tried to create a regular expression to grab these XML documents from a text file, and it does work for most of them, but for some I get an catastrophic backtracking error. I think it's because the text is too large and my expression not very efficient. I'm not really great at regex, so i'm struggling to fix this.

The pattern i'm looking for is:
`<namespace:envelope attributes>XML</namespace:envelope>`

What i've come up with so far is:
`(?i)<[^:]*?:envelope[^>]*?>.*?<\/[^:]*?:envelope>`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to use this regular expression:

`#<([^/].*?):envelope\s.+?</\1:envelope>#s`

[RegEx101 Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/2aLGnm/2)

Or shorter one, if you don't need to have namespace separately:

`#<([^/].*?:envelope)\s.+?</\1>#s`

[RegEx101 Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/2aLGnm/3)

Comment: \1 won't work in every language. It also won't match simple envelope without attributes like `<ns1:envelope>content</ns1:envelope>`

Comment: @stej4n, i don't know know which language using topicstarter, i've just posted a working solution for his answer: `The pattern i'm looking for is: <namespace:envelope ATTRIBUTES>XML</namespace:envelope>`

Comment: I know and there is no universal regex for this, especially if working with JavaScript. Language should be mentioned in answer. Your answer is valid with PCRE and Python, that's why didn't downvoted it ;)