# Delete everything but dates Sublime Regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am matching all date formats in my file  using the regex `([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+)-+([0-9]+)` now how can i delete everything else but the matches? Thanks

Here is an example

```
     <Data ss:Type="String">2017-03-10 15:57:34</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">0</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">Evelyne</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">Evelyne</Data>
    </Cell>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">170212</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">everest</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">everest</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">sdfsd@gmail.com</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String"></Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">2017-04-29 10:21:09</Data>
```

I need to delete everything but the dates in Sublime using mac, thanks.

Comment: In Notepad++ or Sublime? Please provide an example text with expected output. In Notepad++, it can be done easily even when you have several dates on the same line, and you need to get a list of dates each on a separate line.

Comment: Why would that be useful? You'd be left with a list of orphaned dates that mean nothing, so this is the perfect sign that you're asking an XY question: you want to do something and you think removing all the text but the dates makes that happen. What *is* that thing, though, because there is probably a better solution than what you're currently thinking of.

Comment: using sublime! here is the a sample

Comment: okay but the question is still: why? The data becomes meaningless numbers if you do that. Also, you're showing XML, why not just run it through an XML parser that grabs the dates and ignores everything else? Because [don't use regex to parse XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex).

Comment: Try `(?s)([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)|(?:(?![0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+).)+` with `$1\n`. But it is highly inefficient.

Comment: Perfect!! thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Depending on the size of the file you could also search for the regex and click `Find All` to select only the dates and copy/paste them into another document or invert the selection and press backspace and then enter to remove everything but the dates.

Answer (score 1):

In the menu: Find -> Find

Enter your regex, then press FindAll

In the menu: Edit -> Copy

Delete contents of the file

In the menu: Edit -> Paste