# How to get a xml element value in tcl?

Tags: tcl

Trying to get the value of an element to a tcl variable
sample stats.xml file

```
<account>
    <name>abc</name>
    <number>1224.3414</number>
</account>
```

In the above case trying to extract only one element value either name or number

```
set value
regexp "<$number>(.*?)</number>" stats.xml value
```

Comment: Please edit the question to add code you have used to try this.

Comment: updated..pretty new here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Peter says, it is best to use tdom. Trying to parse xml with regexp's will lead to a world of pain. (see [Why is it such a bad idea to parse XML with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex))

That said, if you insist on doing it, then these are the changes you need to your script.

First you need to get the *contents* of the file into a variable. You are using the regexp on the file's name.

```
% set fp [open stats.xml]
file5
% set contents [read $fp]
<account>
    <name>abc</name>
    <number>1224.3414</number>
</account>
% close $fp
```

You also have an error in your pattern (the $ sign in front of `number`). In addition `value` will have the entire match. You will need an extra variable (`v` below), to get just the first match, that is the number. So do the following:

```
% regexp "<number>(.*?)</number>" $contents value v
1
% puts $v
1224.3414
```

Answer (score 2):

It's usually best to go directly to a DOM-handling utility such as `tdom`:

```
package require tdom
set f [open stats.xml]
set xml [read $f]
set doc [dom parse $xml]
$doc selectNodes {string(//number)}
```

The last line returns the value `1224.3414`.

Documentation:
[tdom (package)](http://tdom.github.io)

Comment: is it possible to do this without tdom?

Comment: Sure. It's just a bit harder to write, probably slower, and more likely to result in errors.

Comment: If you insist on doing it without tdom, see my answer. But you really should use tdom (or similar)

Comment: if tdom as binary extension is not viable for you, you might test TclXML https://sourceforge.net/projects/tclxml/ which has a tcl-only version of a xml-parser. Speed might be a problem, depending on data size