# How do I grab html data from inside a table?

Tags: java, html, regex

I am trying to create a web scraper program that takes tables from a website and converts them into ".csv" files.

I'm using Jsoup to pull the data down into a document and have it read from document.html() *doc.html() below*. The reader as it stands picks up 18 tables at my test site but no table data  tags.

Do you have any idea what could be going wrong?

```
ArrayList<Data_Log> container = new ArrayList<Data_Log>();
ArrayList<ListData_Log> containerList = new ArrayList<ListData_Log>();
ArrayList<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<String>();// Stores native names of tables
ArrayList<Double> meanStorage = new ArrayList<Double>();// Stores data mean per table
ArrayList<String> processlog = new ArrayList<String>();// Keeps a record of all actions taken per iteration
ArrayList<Double> modeStorage = new ArrayList<Double>();
Calendar cal;

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8174362940798098542L;

public void takeData() throws IOException {
    if (testModeActive == true) {
        System.out.println("Initializing Data Cruncher with developer logs");
        System.out.println("Taking data from: " + dataSource);      }
    int irow = 0;
    int icolumn = 0;
    int iTable = 0;
    // int iListno = 0;
    // int iListLevel;

    String u = null;
    boolean recording = false;
    boolean duplicate = false;
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(dataSource).get();
    Webtitle = doc.title();
    Pattern tb = Pattern.compile("<table");
    Matcher tB = tb.matcher(doc.html());
    Pattern ttl = Pattern.compile("<title>(//s+)</title>");
    Matcher ttl2= ttl.matcher(doc.html());
    Pattern tr = Pattern.compile("<tr");
    Matcher tR = tr.matcher(doc.html());
    Pattern td = Pattern.compile("<td(//s+)</td>");
    Matcher tD = td.matcher(doc.html());
    Pattern tdc = Pattern.compile("<td class=(//s+)>(//s+)</td>");
    Matcher tDC = tdc.matcher(doc.html());
    Pattern tb2 = Pattern.compile("</table>");
    Matcher tB2 = tb2.matcher(doc.html());
    Pattern th = Pattern.compile("<th");
    Matcher tH = th.matcher(doc.html());
    while (tB.find()) {
        iTable++;

        while(ttl2.find()) {
        tableNames.add(ttl2.group(1));
        }
        while (tR.find()) {

            while (tD.find()||tH.find()) {
                u = tD.group(1);
                Data_Log v = new Data_Log();
                v.setTable(iTable);
                v.dataSort(u);
                v.setRow(irow);
                v.setColumn(icolumn);
                container.add(v);
                icolumn++;
            }
            while(tDC.find()) {
                u = tDC.group(2);
                Data_Log v = new Data_Log();
                v.setTable(iTable);
                v.dataSort(u);
                v.setRow(irow);
                v.setColumn(icolumn);
                container.add(v);
                icolumn++;
            }
            irow++;
        }

        if (tB2.find()) {
        irow=0;
        icolumn=0;
        }       
    }
```

**Expected results:**

`table# logged + "td"s logged`

**Actual result:**

`table# logged "td"s` omitted

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jsoup, use it

```
var url = "<your url>";
var doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
var tables = doc.body().getElementsByTag("table");
tables.forEach(table -> {
    System.out.println(table.id());
    System.out.println(table.className());  
    System.out.println(table.getElementsByTag("td"));
});
```

For your tries to parse html with regex, here's some suggested reading

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

[Why is it such a bad idea to parse XML with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex)

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)