# What symbol is to be used for the below pattern to compile

Tags: java

data: `<emp_dist_nm>Shyam lal/tester</emp_dist_nm>`

code i tried is

```
Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("<emp_dist_nm>(\\S+)</emp_dist_nm>");
```

The pattern is not getting compile, kindly suggest the exact symbol i need to use so that my pattern can compile

Comment: data: <emp_dist_nm>Shyam lal/tester</emp_dist_nm>

code i tried is 
Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("<emp_dist_nm>(\\S+)</emp_dist_nm>");

The pattern is not getting compile, kindly suggest the exact symbol i need to use so that my pattern can compile

Comment: I suggest using a regex site like regex101.com to check your regex -> https://regex101.com/r/mhCWSz/1

Comment: Well, you are looking for `\S+`, but there is a `\s` in the name.

Comment: @tobias_k I suppose your edit is very confusing, as you fixed the escaping error on the fly.

Comment: @GyroGearless No, I did not fix any errors, I just marked it as code. The missing \ was just how SO rendered the non-code-regex

Comment: @GyroGearless see the side-by-side markdown of the edit, you see that tobias_k just edited the markdown to render correctly

Comment: So then the pattern compiles fine, @SambeetDas what is the exact error message?

Comment: Don't parse XML with a regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex

Answer (score 3):

The pattern *does* compile, it just does not match the string. You are looking for `\S+`, but that does not match the space in the name. Instead, you could, e.g., try "everything except `<`", i.e. `[^<]+`

```
Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("<emp_dist_nm>([^<]+)</emp_dist_nm>");
```

In fact, since you already have the closing tag after the group you want to capture, you could also just use `.+?`, i.e. a non-greedy group of *any* character. Here, the non-greedy `?` is important, otherwise it might merge the contents of two such tags and everything in between.

```
Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("<emp_dist_nm>(.+?)</emp_dist_nm>");
```

If you also want to allow empty tags, use `*` instead of `+`, i.e. `[^<]*` or `.*?`.

Comment: I don't know what OPs requirements are, but maybe `[^<]*` would be better if empty tags are allowed

Comment: one more thing if the value between the tags is empty                    
 <emp_dist_nm></emp_dist_nm>, what is the symbol i need to use while compiling

Comment: @SambeetDas As Lino said, use `*` instead of `+`. See my edit.