# Get content between tags with variable attribute

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble writing a regex.
I have to get a string contained between `<cite></cite>` tags, I did using this pattern
`'/>(.*)<\/cite>/'`, but due to changed needs, this tag might now contain or not a `title` attribute with variable content and it might be preceded or not by other tags.

Some examples of possible strings are:
* `<cite>Jhon</cite>`
* `<cite title="a title">Jhon</cite>`
* `<cite title="another title">Jhon</cite>`
* `<blockquote>....<cite title="title">Jhon</cite></blockquote>`

Thus, my pattern doesn't work anymore becouse in example from the last string it would take anything between the `>` of the `<blockquote>` tag and `</cite>`.

How should I change my regex to get `Jhon` from those strings?

Comment: Why not using a DOM parser?

Comment: Because this is a string sent to a PHP function which will manipulate it and will give the modified string as response, to get the name is just part of the process which is needed to take decisions about how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
<cite[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/cite>
```

Explanation

- `<cite[^>]*>` match until `>` is found (Non Greedy)
- `([^<]+)` match until `<` is found (Group the middle text)
  Read the first match group
- `<\/cite>` match closing tag `</cite>` is found

here is the demo
https://regex101.com/r/6RtBfC/1

P.S. Using regex to parse the HTML tags isn't recommended

Comment: @Toto `<cite[^>]*>(.+?)<\/cite>` would fix the cases given by you but using regex for parsing html isn't recommended.

Comment: The second case is also wrong with your updated regex

Comment: @Toto would love to see your test cases for regex that should pass as well as your solution

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Updated the regex to capture multiple tags present in the same line.

Using regex to parse XML is a [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex) idea. If you are still interested in a regex based solution, the following will do:

`<cite.*?>(.*?)<\/cite>`

All I am doing is using the start of `<cite>` tag as well in my regex, along with any attributes it might contain. Lazy approach is being used to capture multiple tags available in the same line.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HWnT70/4)

Comment: [doesn't work when multiple tags on single line](https://regex101.com/r/HWnT70/2)