# regular expression

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

I need a regular expression that selects the element that does not contain `@href`

```
<test  abc="xyz_CHCFGRc/abc_CHmnop" href="sdddzus.xml">text</test>
<test  abc="abc_abc>text23</test>
<test  abc="123_ABCc/abc_CHmnoph">text42</test>
```

Regular expression which I wrote :

```
<test\s+abc.[^href]*>.*
```

the problem with this expression is that href is considered as a seperate letter and if the abc contains any of these letters it doesn't get selected.

The result should be:

```
<test  abc="abc_abc>text23</test>
<test  abc="123_ABCc/abc_CHmnoph">text42</test>
```

but in my case the result is

```
<test  abc="abc_abc>text23</test>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably be using an XML parser, rather than regex.

Comment: Not probably - definitely. And it would be trivial in XPath/XSLT to select `test[not(@href)]`. Not sure why this question is tagged as `xslt` if regex is the expected solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should use XML parser for that: [Why is it such a bad idea to parse XML with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex). But if you have to use regular expresisons, here's the solution:

Try `<test(?!.+href).+`

Exaplanation:

`<test` - match `<test` literally

`(?!.+href)` - negative lookahead: assert what follows is not: `.+` - one or more of any characters and `href`, i.e. assert what follows does not contain `href` word

`.+` - match noe or more of any characters

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pHdh99/1)

Your idea about negated character class is wrong: `[^href]` negates `h`, `r`, `e` and `f` separately, it does not negate `href` as a word.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex to match a full line not containing the word "href":

```
^((?!href).)*$
```