# regex for matching string with multiple occurance in java

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex expresssion which match below strings in java.

```
select * from test

select * from test where a=100

select * from test where a=100 and b=100
```

the select statement may or may not contain where condition, also it may contain 1 to n number of conditions, i need a single regex to match all of those, can anyone help

i tried to match the string by using below regex expression, but it fails 
`select (([A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}(|\\,))*|\\*) from ([A-Za-z0-9]{1,20})( where ([A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}((| )(\\=|\\>|\\<)(| ))[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20})|$)`

**Criteria:**

i) a string should start with **select**

ii) if **where** is present it should be followed by a pair of variable and value

```
  like below:

        `select * from test where a=10;`
```

iii) Between two variable and value pair  **and** should be present

```
  like below:
         `select * from test where a=10 and b=10`
```

iv) a string may or may not contain **where**

v) a string should not end with **and**

```
public class Test {
public static Pattern pattern;
public static Matcher matcher;

private static final String PATTERN="(\\s)*select(\\s)+((\\*)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+))(\\s)+from(\\s)+[a-zA-Z0-9]*(\\s)+where(\\s)+(‌​[a-zA-Z0-9]*(\\s)*=(\\s)*[0-9]*)+(\\s)*((\\s)*and(\\s)*([a-zA-Z0-9]*(\\s)*=(\\s)*[0-9]*)‌​)*(\\s)*";


public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String data;        
    pattern=Pattern.compile(PATTERN,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    do{         
    data=br.readLine();
    matcher=pattern.matcher(data);
    if(matcher.find()){
        System.out.print("True");
    }else{
        System.out.print("false");
    }
    System.out.print(":"+data+":\n");
    }while(data!="exit");
}
```

}

**Test Cases(should show true)**

select a from test

select a from test where a=10

select a from test where a=10 and b=10

select a from test where a=10 and b=10 and c=10

**Test Cases(should show false)**

select a from test where

select a from test where a=10 and

select a from test where a=10 b=10

select a from test where a=10 and b=10 and

thanks

Comment: You ought to make a start on this and submit your progress: that way we know how to gauge the answer detail.

Comment: @Pradeep I'd put that into your question

Comment: Please put your regular expression in the actual question: it doesn't really belong in a comment; you'll attract downvoting the way things are.

Comment: So you just want to match each line beginning with `select * from test`, or you want to parse the conditions or...? Can you give an expected output?

Comment: its like sql select statment, it may be vary on each case. 

below are the example string
select a from test
select a,b from group
select * from group where a=1 and b=10
etc

Comment: Don't forget to escape the backslashes: you need \\ rather than \.

Comment: So you want to match any `select` sql statement? Can you just match everything from one `select` to the next `select` keyword?

Comment: @Pradeep please differentiate between **match string** and **validate syntax**!

Comment: yes i want to match sql select statement

Comment: @bobbel

Regex Expression: 

`select (([A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}(|\\,))*|\\*) from ([A-Za-z0-9]{1,20})( where ([A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}((| )(\\=|\\>|\\<)(| ))[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20})|$)`

matching String:

**select a from test** 
**select a,b from group** 
**select * from group where a=1 and b=10**

Comment: Phrasing it differently: is [this](http://regex101.com/r/tP3vD1) enough? Why/were are you matching the strings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139926/regular-expression-to-match-common-sql-syntax

Comment: @robin thanks for your quick response.  the expression matching all string, it even its wrong.  It should match : **select * from test**  not **select * from test** where  if **where** is present, it should be followed by a variable and a value  if more then one variable and value pair occurs it should be followed by a **and**

Comment: @Pradeep: yes, it will match those. This means you have more requirements. Please edit your question to let us know *exactly* what you want to match/don't match, why, how... There are many ways to match the 3 strings you gave. Explain which one you need.

Comment: @robin i have updated my requirement to the question

Comment: @bobbel: so you are saying there is no solution for this?

Comment: @Pradeep I mean: with a regular expression, you are not able to validate **all** SQL statements (since you didn't mention what you really want to match or validate). May I ask you, what you really want to do? What do you want to achieve by matching these statements? From whom do you get these statements? You could just use a SQL parser if you want to parse SQL, couldn't you? Did you know, that there could be aliases, string functions and other cool things? At this point I want to ask another question: which SQL dialect do you want to use? Any?

Comment: @bobbel

i don't want to validate all the select statement in SQL, i need to validate the above cases alone, its a part in my college project, need to validate user select statement string. doing my project in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found solution for my question. this will match all my criteria.

`select\s(([A-Za-z0-9]{1,20})(|\,[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20})+|\*)\sfrom\s([A-Za-z0-9]{1,20})(\swhere\s[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}\=[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}($|(\sand\s[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}\=[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20})+$)|$)`

Hope it will help anyone in future.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Regular expressions. After reading this question i tried the following in online regex testers. it works fine.

```
(\s)*select(\s)+((\*)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+))(\s)+from(\s)+[a-zA-Z0-9]*(\s)+where(\s)+([a-zA-Z0-9]*(\s)*=(\s)*[0-9]*)+((\s)+and(\s)+([a-zA-Z0-9]*(\s)*=(\s)*[0-9]*))*(\s)*
```

I think it is too long. But it works fine for case 2 and case 3. If you want to achieve only these cases through regex , you need two regex to achieve your desired solution.

If you want to achieve all the three in single regex its not possible[According to my knowledge] .
[**As Bobbel mentioned in comments**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139926) , Its not possible.

Because you need to check whether "where" is present or not . If present , it should have condition. Else "where" itself shouldn't be present.

**EDIT**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class HelloWorld
{
  private static final String PATTERN="(\\s)*select(\\s)+((\\*)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+))   (\\s)+from(\\s)+[a-zA-Z0-9]*(\\s)+where(\\s)+([a-zA-Z0-9]*(\\s)*=(\\s)*[0-9]*)+ ((\\s)+and(\\s)+([a-zA-Z0-9]*(\\s)*=(\\s)*[0-9]*))*(\\s)*";

 public static void main(String []args)
 {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    String data="select * from asdf where a  = 20 and ax =20";        
    Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(PATTERN); 
    Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(data);
    if(matcher.find())
    {
      System.out.print("True");
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.print("false");
    }
    System.out.print(":"+data+":\n");
 }
```

}

[image: See screenshots]

Comment: It is also possible matching all three in one with something like this: `select...([\s]+where...([\s]+and...)*)*` - http://regex101.com/r/uY2iP0. But anyway, you are very strict with these expressions. What about `IS NULL` or `<`, `>`, `>=`, `<=`. I still don't know, what @Pradeep expects...

Comment: Yeah it's still possible. It ll be too large regex. He specifies only "and" . So i din't check for relational operators.

Comment: That's what i given above in that regex. It works even if you add 100 "and".

Comment: @user3168736: the regex which you provided is not satisfying my criteria which i mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Pradeep Try the following `(\s)*select(\s)+((\*)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+))(\s)+from(\s)+[a-zA-Z0-9]*(\s)+where(\s)+([a-zA-Z0-9]*(\s)*=(\s)*[0-9]*)+(\s)*((\s)*and(\s)*([a-zA-Z0-9]*(\s)*=(\s)*[0-9]*))*(\s)*` And could you please post your test case examples.

Comment: @user3168736 : i have updated my code and test cases in my question.

Comment: @pradeep , I checked the above cases with [http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/]. As i said u need two or more regex to check cases with `where` condition and without `where` condition. The following regex ll work if you have `where` condition `(\s)*select(\s)+((\*)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+))(\s)+from(\s)+[a-zA-Z0-9]*(\s)+where(\s)+([a-zA-Z0-9]*(\s)*=(\s)*[0-9]*)+((\s)+and(\s)+([a-zA-Z0-9]*(\s)*=(\s)*[0-9]*))*(\s)*`

Comment: It returns false in all the test cases in list 2 and satisfies all the test cases except first in list 1

Comment: @user3168736 :  im getting false only for all test cases

Comment: @user3168736 : please see my edit above , i'm getting false only.

Comment: Error maybe in your pattern declaration. please Check it clearly