# Validate SQL Query with Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate a string that contains following words: `SELECT` and `FROM` but do not contain a group of words like `CREATE`, `DROP`, `UPDATE` etc.

To be more specific, i want to ensure that a user will execute only SELECT query statements on my system.

What Ii've got so far is the following regex:

```
^(?!.*(CREATE|DROP|UPDATE|INSERT|ALTER|DELETE|ATTACH|DETACH)).*$
```

but how can i know if the string has `SELECT` and `FROM` in the correct order -> `SELECT .... FROM ....`.

More requirements for the regex. I want to regex to be valid if the query is like :
 1.  `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME ='ALTER'` 
 2. `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FILENAME ='ATTACHMENT'`
 3. Actually the regex needs be invalid if there is any word from the group: `ALTER`, `DROP`, etc with a `" "`(space) before and after each word

Regarding the first bullet : i'm thinking if the name of someone is 'ALTER JOHN' then the query will be invalid -> which is not true

**I appreciate that you guys are telling me that is a bad idea. I agree and i know. There's no risk, each user will have their own DB. The question was regarding the REGEX. Thanks !**
**Also, the query will run on SQLITE database**

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: Replace `$` with `SELECT.*FROM` (as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4389666/3832970))

Comment: Honestly, a better way to approach solving the problem of only allowing the user to do SELECT statements is to create a user in the sql server that [only has SELECT permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authorization-and-permissions-in-sql-server).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match common SQL syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139926/regular-expression-to-match-common-sql-syntax)

Comment: Don't do this. It's a bad idea.

Comment: _each user will have their own DB_ ... oh dear.  You should ask another question about that as well :-)

Comment: *There's no risk* The risk is you **think** this will stop doing SQL injection. [It won't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420198/validate-sql-query-with-regular-expression#comment91783789_52420241) and you can't assume that this will. The illusion of this being "safe" is more dangerous than knowing that it's not. The correct solution here is to not inject SQL into your code and use parameterised queries.

Comment: About your update, when a professional contractor asks you *"A client has asked me to build and install a custom shelving system. I'm at the point where I need to nail it, but I'm not sure what to use to pound the nails in. Should I use an old shoe or a glass bottle?"* you should answer "[neither, your approach is wrong and you should be using a hammer to do this kind of work.](https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925)"

Comment: So is the new requirement that the query has to contain one of two possible `WHERE` clauses?

Comment: No , what i want right now is like : ^(?=.*SELECT.*FROM)(?!.*(?:CREATE |DROP |UPDATE |INSERT |ALTER |DELETE |ATTACH |DETACH )).*$ with one " " space after each word. How do i manage to look for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add a *positive* lookahead which checks for the presence of `SELECT ... FROM`:

```
^(?=.*SELECT.*FROM)(?!.*(?:CREATE|DROP|UPDATE|INSERT|ALTER|DELETE|ATTACH|DETACH)).*$
```

While this answers your question, I am worried, because you tagged your question with C#, implying that you are needing to do this from your C# application.  In general, you should *not* ever allow raw SQL code coming in from the outside to execute in your C# code.  Instead, always use a prepared statement, where user inputs can be safely sterilized before they run in a query.

If you want a case insensitive match, then use the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag when creating your regex:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^your pattern$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I know what are you meaning but this is what i actually want. Thanks a lot! Regarding your answer, that regex  is case sensitive, how can i remove that?

Comment: Thanks! I need to wait 10 min before i can accept an answer.

Comment: `declare @sql varchar(max); set @sql = 'DRO'; set @sql = @sql + "P TABLE SomeImportantTable"; sp_executesql @sql` just sayin.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I gave the caveat that, if being done from a C# application, statements should be used.  In that case, the user wouldn't even be able to choose with _statement_ gets executed, beyond also not being able to inject anything into a query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the comment was more to reinforce your warning to the OP, not to disagree with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
const regex = /(\s*([\0\b\'\"\n\r\t\%\_\\]*\s*(((select\s+\S.*\s+from\s+\S+)|(insert\s+into\s+\S+)|(update\s+\S+\s+set\s+\S+)|(delete\s+from\s+\S+)|(((drop)|(create)|(alter)|(backup))\s+((table)|(index)|(function)|(PROCEDURE)|(ROUTINE)|(SCHEMA)|(TRIGGER)|(USER)|(VIEW))\s+\S+)|(truncate\s+table\s+\S+)|(exec\s+)|(\/\*)|(--)))(\s*[\;]\s*)*)+)/i;
```

This regex check if input contains SQL query.
https://regex101.com/r/XxO2J3/5