# php split on each whitespace, but not after specific word to create array from string

Tags: php, arrays, split, preg-match-all

Take this string:

```
$string = "wanted NOT IN OR"

preg_match_all('/\w+/', $string, $WordArray);
//  outputs each word into array
```

But what if I do not want to split on the whitespace right after the word "`NOT`".
Keeping the word "NOT" and the following word together, and then keep splitting as usual.

The array should end up looking like this:

```
$WordArray = [
    'wanted',
    'NOT IN',
    'OR'
'];
```

Did try with something like this, but.. yeah. That did not split as expected...

```
$WordArray = preg_split('/\s|\bNOT\s/');
```

Comment: What are the possible values of `$string`?

Comment: could be a lot. But the first word would always be a database fieldname (which could be just about any word. Next could be `IN | BETWEEN | LIKE | AND | OR`, and sometimes with `NOT` i front of one or more of these words...

Comment: How about this regex `/NOT\s\w+|\w+/`?

Comment: So something like this? https://3v4l.org/4Q6fi

Comment: Yes. The first regex seems to do the trick. Thanks. I couldn't figure out how to use the | part in this..

Comment: [Regular expression to match common SQL syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/139926/2943403)  When you ask for a regex solution, but offer very limited sample data, the reliability of our advice will not be awesome.

Comment: Im sorry. But yes. The regex was for a shorthand string for the where clause. And the complete string is in fact `wanted NOT IN OR` where the first word is fieldname, and the second could be one of the keywords i mentioned, and at last the `OR` is if I need to change the default AND to `OR`..